# No HDMI sound on TV from HTPC

Tags: audio, hdmi, htpc

Ok, so I just finished putting together a new HTPC and everything works great. I had it connected to my 24" LCD monitor via HDMI and got great video AND audio. However, when I connect the same cable to my 55" LCD TV, I get only video and no audio. I'm guessing its not a PC setting, coz the audio works great on the monitor. Any thoughts? My TV is a Vizio E550VL and my graphics card is a GIGABYTE HD 4350.

Comment: when you connect it to the TV does the default audio device change?

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this problem before. When you connect your PC to TV different settings are used. You need to explicitly tell your PC to channel the audio through HDMI when connected to your PC. This is what i did to fix the problem on **Windows 7**. May differ slightly on your OS.

1. Right click on the speaker icon in the task-bar
2. Click "playback devices".
3. Here select which device you want as default(in your case the TV).

Answer (score 1):

When you had video and audio from you 24" LCD did you have ANY other audio cables (like an 1/8" analog stereo cable) attached to your monitor as well?  To verify that you were getting your video and audio through your HDMI cable to your 24" LCD monitor make sure that NOTHING except the HDMI cable and a power cable are plugged into the monitor.

If after this if you are 100% sure you are getting audio through the HDMI cable then I would check the audio settings of your 55" LCD.  Many of TVs that take an HDMI cable have settings to accept digital video over HDMI while using analog audio from a composite source.  Make sure everything on your 55" LCD is set to digital for your HDMI connection.

Also make sure you are not using any adapters (DVI to HDMI).  Sound cannot be passed through a DVI adapter (plus it will break the HDCP compliancy).

Comment: Yes, there was NOTHING else connected to the 24" monitor except the HDMI cable and the power cord. No other audio cable was connected. I am also not using any adapters of any sort. It is pure HDMI to HDMI. I also have an xbox connected to the same TV via HDMI and get audio no problem. IDK why it won't play the audio from the HTPC.

Comment: @mrthinker have you tried using the same HDMI cable that you use with your Xbox or using a different HDMI cable?  There are several different standards for HDMI cables, maybe your cable isn't compatible with either the GPU in your HTPC or your 55" LCD.