# HDMI Sound for HTPC

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi, htpc

I have the (perhaps) the same problem as stated in this other [HDMI sound to HTPC](https://superuser.com/questions/217852/no-hdmi-sound-on-tv-from-htpc) question.  I tried the advice of clicking on the speaker in the system tray.  I can see the HDMI audio device I want to use.  That device claims to be functioning properly.  But there is no sound, and it won't let me select it as the active audio device.

When I click on the troubleshooter, it says that there are no speakers connected.

I would think this is because my computer us unable to pipe sound through the video card (preventing the HDMI from carrying it), except that it truly claims that it has an HDMI sound device that is working correctly.  So I'm not sure what is wrong at this point.  Thoughts?

My system is Windows 7 x64.  In case it makes a difference, the video card I'm using is this [GeForce GTX 560](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FUJ8OY)

Comment: Is the display that's receiving the HDMI signal set to use HDMI as it's audio source?

Comment: Have you used the **Nvidia Control Panel** to *enable* the audio through the HDMI interface?  Usually you will only get 2-channel stereo.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your on board sound in your BIOS. It would most likely be under the advanced tab in the BIOS.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/privileges/comment).